# How to export same size images from html table to excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, excel

I am facing some issues in exporting the image from html table. when I clicked on export button to download the html table as excel file. The downloaded xls file has different size of image. I want to export the images with the size as in the html table.

I am using following code, please give suitable suggestions regarding the problem. any other suggestion are also helpful.

```
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:2px solid red;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="divTable">
<center>
    <table>
<caption>Person Information</caption>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>contact</th>
<th>Image</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="4"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3rlUFLRgsZ9kWB2DHyelOZdsRn6vXm2HlXKULG5qfYQZVYSrClw" alt="Flowers in Chania" width="80px" height="80px"></td>
<td >Male</td>
<td>7665716415</td>
<td>image</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Male</td>
<td>7665716415</td>
<td>image</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Male</td>
<td>7665716415</td>
<td><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS58D5NJFzmB2W_6tdzSVIJdHd8o_aACbV2Dh5AUHbODb62Q0r8Ew" alt="Abdevilliers" width="50px" height="50px"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Male</td>
<td>image</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<center>
<button id="myButton">Export Table data into Excel</button>
</center>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>  
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#divTable').html()));
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try with percentage height and width instead of pixcel,

If in percentage your html view is not getting proper than You can show html in pixcel and when you are going to export it you will update to percentage.

Comment: Please check this js bin https://jsbin.com/mafayoqixa/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Adjust your require size in percentage for exporting excel,  and when you are showing on web apply as pixcel, so you need to replace pixcel value to percentage while exporting.

Comment: Sorry dear, here you will not be provided execution you will get idea/suggestion. now you need to execute that suggestion with your hand. Edit your self and show here if not working. than you will get suggestion around it.

Comment: i edited my code according to your previous suggestions but all are not working.